# Serve Apache from home directory and use ssh with private key

Tags: apache, continuous-integration

I'm dealing with a web application that is serving a website from a user's home directory through Apache; it's configured that way and I would prefer not changing that (never touch a running system). I would like to setup a deployment from Gitlab to this server that uses a private key to copy the repository via `rsync` and `ssh`. The problem is, that even after `ssh-copy-id`, it prompts for a password, because the home folder on the web server has 777 permissions (see https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/4491/322894). But prompting for a password would break the deployment script, and if I changed it from 777 to 700 or similar, Apache can't serve the website anymore.

For now, the only solution I see is let let the CI script login as root. But is there a better way?

Comment: why does Apache httpd need to _write_ (7) to the directory, in order to serve it?

Comment: Thank you for hinting, I just read up a bit more, changed its group to apache and chmodded 750, now both desired functionalities are working.